# Getting header controller not defined error in Angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I am getting headercontroller not defined error. I have reference this controller.js file in Index.html and is there anything i am missing

Controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('headerController', headerController);

    headerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http' ,'$rootScope'];
    function headerController($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
    }

})();
```

app.js

```
(function () {

    var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

    myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

        $stateProvider
          .state('route1', {
              url: "/route1",
              templateUrl: "SOC/Views/route1.html",
              controller: "route1ctrl"
          })
          .state('route2', {
              url: "/route2",
              templateUrl: "SOC/Views/route2.html",
              controller: "route2ctrl"
          })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    });


})();
```

Index.html

```
  <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="SOC/Directives/Header/controller.js"></script>
```

I tried even this below code it does not work

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('headerController', headerController);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwrite the dependency of the angular module by providing empty array

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('headerController', headerController);
```

Remove the array from module('myApp)

```
angular
.module('myApp')
    .controller('headerController', headerController);
```

Controller.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function headerController($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
    }
    headerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http' ,'$rootScope'];

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('headerController', headerController);
})();
```

More about $inject in angularjs - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di